# Pass concatenated string as function argument in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a concatenated string and pass it to a function. Suppose, I want to create a list of data frame that I can pass into a function. The problem is that the concatenated string using "noquote" function is treated as a "noquote" object, not as a list that I want. Here's a reproducible example. If I define data using `data <- dflist1`, then I get what I want, but when I try `data1 <- noquote(paste0("dflist", selection))`, it does not return the same list.

Is there a way I can create the list as I want by only changing `selection`?

In the real problem I face, there're multiple function arguments that I need to change in this way, so learning how to do this trick would be very helpful.

Any comments would be much appreciated!

```
a <- data.frame(aa = c(1,2,3), bb = c(4,5,6))
b <- data.frame(cc = c(11,12,13), dd = c(41,51,61))

dflist1 <- list(a, b)
dflist2 <- list(a, b, a, b)

selection <- "1"   # I want to make a choice here

data <- dflist1
data1 <- noquote(paste0("dflist", selection))

print(data1)
[1] dflist1

print(data)
[[1]]
  aa bb
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6

[[2]]
  cc dd
1 11 41
2 12 51
3 13 61

class(data)
[1] "list"
class(data1)
[1] "noquote"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `get` to return the values

```
get(data1)
#[[1]]
#  aa bb
#1  1  4
#2  2  5
#3  3  6

#[[2]]
#  cc dd
#1 11 41
#2 12 51
#3 13 61
```

If we check the `str(data1)`, will understand that on top of "character", it adds a `class` `noquote`

```
str(data1)
#'noquote' chr "dflist1"

class(data1)
#[1] "noquote"
```

by changing the attribute

```
noquote
#function (obj, right = FALSE) 
#{
#    if (!inherits(obj, "noquote")) 
#        class(obj) <- c(attr(obj, "class"), if (right) c(right = "noquote") else "noquote")
#    obj
#}
```

The `paste0` returns the object name as string and there is no need to use `noquote`.  Simply, wrap with `get` and it returns the value of that `list` or use `mget` if there are multiple objects

Comment: Super! Thank you so much!